# Build and deploy AWS Lambda of type image using SAM in Gitlab runner

Tags: aws-lambda, gitlab-ci, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to set up CI/CD for an AWS Lambda using the SAM cli tool inside a Gitlab runner.

My Lambda function is a Go app shipped as a container image.

I followed this article to set it up properly:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/using-gitlab-ci-cd-pipeline-to-deploy-aws-sam-applications/

Unfortunately, the used `.gitlab-ci.yml` seems to be only applicable to functions of `PackageType` `Zip`, i.e. by uploading the application code to an S3 bucket:

```
image: python:3.8

stages:
  - deploy

production:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - pip3 install awscli --upgrade
    - pip3 install aws-sam-cli --upgrade
  script:
    - sam build
    - sam package --output-template-file packaged.yaml --s3-bucket #S3Bucket#
    - sam deploy --template-file packaged.yaml --stack-name gitlab-example --s3-bucket #S3Bucket# --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --region us-east-1
  environment: production
```

I adjusted the script to these lines:

```
script:
    - sam build
    - sam deploy
```

`sam build` fails at this stage:

```
Building codeuri: /builds/user/app runtime: None metadata: {'DockerTag': 'go1.x-v1', 'DockerContext': '/builds/user/app/hello-world', 'Dockerfile': 'Dockerfile'} architecture: x86_64 functions: ['HelloWorldFunction']
Building image for HelloWorldFunction function
Build Failed
Error: Building image for HelloWorldFunction requires Docker. is Docker running?
```

[This guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) at Gitlab suggests using `image: docker` with `dind` enabled, so I tried this config:

```
image: docker

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - deploy

production:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - pip3 install awscli --upgrade
    - pip3 install aws-sam-cli --upgrade
  script:
    - sam build
    - sam deploy
  environment: production
```

This in turn fails because the base `docker` image does not ship Python. How can I combine those two approaches to have Docker and SAM available at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. use the `docker` image and install python in your job OR
2. use the `python` image and install docker in your job OR
3. build your own image containing all your dependencies (docker, python, awscli, etc) and use that as your job's `image:`.

Installing python in the docker image:

```yaml
production:
  image: docker
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apk add --update python3 py3-pip
    - pip3 install awscli --upgrade
    - pip3 install aws-sam-cli --upgrade
  script:
    - sam build
    - sam deploy
  environment: production
```

Installing docker in the Python image:

```yaml
production:
  image: python:3.9-slim
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends docker.io
    - pip3 install awscli --upgrade
    - pip3 install aws-sam-cli --upgrade
  script:
    - sam build
    - sam deploy
  environment: production
```

Or build your own image:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
RUN apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends docker.io
```

```sh
docker build -t myregistry.example.com/myrepo/myimage:latest
docker push myregistry.example.com/myrepo/myimage:latest
```

```yaml
production:
  image: myregistry.example.com/myrepo/myimage:latest
  # ...
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for your help. I went with option 1 and extended the `apk` command to properly work with SAM: `apk add --update gcc python3 python3-dev py3-pip linux-headers musl-dev`